# VSTS build failing with error "Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'."

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines

Getting that build failed error because I have 4 warnings that read the same.

```
##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Python Tools\Microsoft.PythonTools.Django.targets(120,5): Warning : Errors while resolving environments: Some project interpreters failed to load:

Interpreter d:\a\1\s\"name of project"\env\ has invalid value for 'Id': env
Interpreter reference has invalid path: Global|PythonCore|3.4
```

I am using Python 3.4.4 64-bit if that makes a difference.

The build is failing during the `Build solution **\*.sln` section of the build.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: It seems you queue your build on hosted agent with vs2015. What's the result if you queue your build on private agent with vs2017? And can you upload your project in one drive?

Comment: @marina-msft Hi i am building on a hosted vs2017 agent. I am able to successfully build on vs2017 with no errors.However when building with VSTS it fails when trying to build my solution. It seems like MSBuild is trying to find a folder called v10.0 in the MSBuild folder when the only version is 15.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit pyproj file to change 10.0 to 15.0

```
<VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
```