# TFS build is getting fail with Zero error with message - Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

I am building a solution file which is having multiple .csproj projects with the TFS(on premises with Build agent on the same network) **MSBuild Task** with version 14.0.
As, This is not giving me any Error but getting fail with one message "**Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.**"

[image]

My MS Build Task:

[image]

Build Agent Configuration:

- VS community 2017
- VS Express 2015 Desktop/Web (update3)

I found a link [VSTS build failing with error "Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150339/vsts-build-failing-with-error-process-msbuild-exe-exited-with-code-1) but unable to understand the exact issue as even error is not coming.

**Full Error log**

> 302 Warning(s)
>       0 Error(s) Time Elapsed 00:02:12.37 Exit code: 1
>
> Error record:
>
> Invoke-VstsTool : Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
>
> At
>   E:\DevOps\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1_work_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4c76-b606-5eaba2196824\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\InvokeFunctions.ps1:111
>   char:13
>   + Invoke-VstsTool -FileName $MSBuildPath -Arguments $arguments -Requir ...
>
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> - CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId :  Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-VstsTool
>
> Script stack trace: at Invoke-Tool,
>   E:\DevOps\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1_work_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba26824\1.120.0\ps_modules\VstsTaskSdk\ToolFunctions.ps1:
>   line 86
>
> at Invoke-MSBuild,
>   E:\DevOps\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1_work_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba26824\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\InvokeFunctions.ps1:
>   line 111
>
> at Invoke-BuildTools,
>   E:\DevOps\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1_work_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba26824\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\InvokeFunctions.ps1:
>   line 36
>
> at ,
>   E:\DevOps\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1_work_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba96824\1.120.0\MSBuild.ps1: line 43
>
> at , : line 1
>
> at , : line 22
>
> at , : line 18
>
> at , : line 1
>
> Exception:
>
> Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Process
>   'msbuild.exe'  exited with code '1'.
>
> Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
>
> Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited
>   with code '1'.
>
> Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
>
> Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed] Leaving Invoke-MSBuild.
>
> Leaving Invoke-BuildTools.
>
> Leaving
>   E:\DevOps\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1_work_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.120.0\MSBuild.ps1.

Thanks..!!

Comment: Try to tun the build with `system.debug` = true and share here the full logs.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk ,  Need to pass this argument on command line ? beacuse this is not working.

Comment: When you queue the build you have an option to change the value of `system.debug`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczy Exception:
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
Leaving Invoke-VstsTool.
Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk how can I send you a full log..?

Comment: Error Log-Exit code: 1
Error record:
Invoke-VstsTool : Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
At E:\DevOps\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.136.1\_work\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.120.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\InvokeFunctions.ps1:111 char:13
+ Invoke-VstsTool -FileName $MSBuildPath -Arguments $arguments -Requir ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-VstsTool

Comment: you can edit your question and paste there the log (only for the ms build task).

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk..posted,,Please check..

Comment: Can you share also your MS Build task? (in the build definition)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk..done!

Comment: In MSBuild version try to change to "Latest".

Comment: I tried..matter is my project is having some dependency of "OracleOutsideIn" on msbuild 14.0  which is not working with Msbuild version 15.0.

Comment: In order to narrow the scope of this issue, please try to create a new blank project and submit it to your TFS build server, then build it check if it still have this issue, if yes, this should be related to your ENV settings, if not, it more related to your projects.

Comment: my another project is getting success..so this might be the project specific issue..

Comment: @DarshanaPatel,Thanks for your reply. So, now we just need to check the project file, have you add any power shell scripts in your project? If yes, you should make sure the PS scripts can be executed success. BTW, have you tried build the project in the build server with MSBuild.exe command line? Since this issue is related to your project, it is difficult to find the reason for us, we need to much more info, even we need to reproduce this issue, but you can troubleshooting it by yourself.

Comment: again one confusion is Project is getting success build by command line so would it be correct if we can say this a project issue..!!